# How can I install a perl module available only to my user ID?

Tags: unix, perl, cpan

I need to install some Perl Modules for my Perl scripts. However those modules are not available on the servers I want to run the scripts on. I also do not want to mess with server wide library directories. I think it can be done by manipulating the "@INC" variable. I need to know how to install the new modules using cpan and the alternate @INC.

Alternatively, it might also make sense to bundle my own Perl binary/environment with my script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Long answer can be found here: http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010015

Short answer, put your modules to, say, `/home/face429/perlmodules`, then in your perl program use: `use lib '/home/face429/perlmodules';`.

To check whether that path has been included to `@INC` usage you can print the `@INC`.

Comment: Thanks Favoretti, and how can I use CPAN to place those modules there?  Keeping in mind, firewalls are not allowing the connection from the server to the internet (I tried CPAN ftp and http). I manaed to use my desktop to get those modules, I want to know where I can transfer them to the server (i.e do I just scp the directory to anywhere ?)

Answer (score 0):

Your *current* directory is part of the path searched by Perl.

`perl -V` will show you the content of @INC, which includes "." (the current directory) at the end.

Note that your current directory is exactly that, not the directory where your script is. If this is to run on a web server, it will break easily.

You can also add a specific path by putting `use lib '/your/perl/modules'` into your script, as explained by favoretti.

Finally, you can add a path for all your scripts through the environment variable `PERLLIB`, so you don't have to `use lib`in every script.

```
PERLLIB=/your/perl/modules
```

or `SET PERLLIB = C:/your/perl/modules` in Windows.